# Android: What is the smoothest way to synchronize a remote database in the background?

Tags: android, database, multithreading, parse-platform

I have an Android database hosted in Parse and I have been trying to find the best way/practices to update my LocalStorage with the latest remote changes.

I'm not asking for code or syntax, I would just be looking for a set of steps to follow, I'm sure I would need to use a worker thread because I don't want to block the UI, I would love to have the transition as smooth as possible for the user (he wouldn't even realise an update is happening) and I want it to happen when the app is on the foreground. The ideas I've gotten so far:

- Use multithreading (Loopers, Handlers, Thread) and update each table in a separate thread.
- Try to throttle the request to minimize the CPU usage and get a table at a time.
- Use a Loader and just listen for the changes.
- Call an IntentService to get table by table also.
- Create an Unbound Service and let the database update after the app is closed.
- Don't update the database in the background and wait until the user actually needs the data and the retrieve it.

I've already tried the IntentService one, it's not as smooth as I would like:

```
public class DataService extends IntentService {
    public DataService() {
        super(DataService.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String[] entities = {
                "Img",
                "Pack",
                "Technology",
                "Term",
                "TermHierarchy",
                "TermImplementation",
                "TermTerm",
                "UserTechnology",
                "UserTerm",
        };

        for (String entity : entities) {
            updateLocalTable(entity);
        }
    }

    private void updateLocalTable(String entity) {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(entity);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null){
                    ParseObject.pinAllInBackground(objects);
                }else {
                    Log.e(TAG_, e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Also, I'm calling it the first time a connection change occur (Wi-Fi available). Should I instead just call it on the onCreate, or create an Alarm to update once every certain amount of time, or just when the Activity is finishing?

I've seen a few post related:

[Update data in Background Periodically (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23513114/update-data-in-background-periodically-android)

[Syncronizing Android client with remote SQL-server database, using web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997997/syncronizing-android-client-with-remote-sql-server-database-using-web-service)

[Send database data through socket connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808256/send-database-data-through-socket-connection)

[sync remote database (mysql) with sqlite database and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171379/sync-remote-database-mysql-with-sqlite-database-and-vice-versa/7171702#7171702)

But none of them have good and detailed answers and they don't really tackle the problem.

I will also add that Parse handles all the RESTful calls and the JSON conversion so I don't have to worry about that.

---

**Edit.**

I just found a video that explains these concepts (and supports the answer provided by @gsgsgs) in less than 2 minutes:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Expbi0lHLRE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [SyncAdapter](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html):

> The sync adapter component in your app encapsulates the code for the tasks that transfer data between the device and a server

It's not very simple to implement, but have some advantages:

- Background sync scheduled by system with other network requests to save battery
- It can be configured by user in sync settings (disable or enable background sync)
- Adapter retry sync automatically if request failed with [exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff)
- You can simple use it with yours ContentProvider
- Adapter can sync in a separate process if you want

[Here](http://blog.udinic.com/2013/07/24/write-your-own-android-sync-adapter) some tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

@Evin1_,

In my opinion the important things are:

1/ **Think about the order:**

If some tables nedds informations from another, start by synchronize them in a correct order

2/ **Use indexes:**

> Indexes are special lookup tables that the database search engine can
>   use to speed up data retrieval

3/ **Use transactions:**

It will give you an opportunity to rollback if something goes wrong

4/ **Multithreading:**

> The speed and efficiency of a long-running, data-intensive operation
>   often improves when you split it into smaller operations running on
>   multiple threads

5/ **Prevent connection lost:**

If the user disables 3G or Wifi you have to be able to know what happend, display error messages or something else.

6/ **The amount of datas:**

If you have a huge amount of datas don't send them in a sinle Json, cut it in smaller packets

*Hope it helps.*

Comment: Both are very good answers, but I will pick the one from @gsgsgs because it is a little bit more Android oriented. Thanks!